# How to Encrypt data after validation in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise for authentication, register. Now i want to save emailId in MySQL in encrypted format. So i use gem 'aescrypt'.

My controller:

```
 def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_user_params)
    @dashboard_user.created_by=current_dashboard_user.username
    @dashboard_user.company_id=current_dashboard_user.company_id
    active_ind = ""
    email = @dashboard_user.email

    if params["active"] == nil then
      active_ind = "0"
    else
      active_ind = "1"
    end

    @dashboard_user.active = active_ind
    @dashboard_user.email= AESCrypt.encrypt(email, "password")

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dashboard_user.save
        format.html { flash[:notice] = 'User successfully Created.' and redirect_to action: "index"}
      else
        @dashboard_user.email = email
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

When i try to save user, it throws Email invalid. I removed validation for email in model. Even though same error exists.
What problem it is?
If there any way to encrypt data after validation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your DashboardUser class? What's the auth key in config/initializers/devise.rb ?

Comment: config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]@Novae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you validate email?
You could use a custom method to decrypt it before validate against (for e.g.) a regex.
Alternatively, you can use [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). In your case, `after_validation` can be useful :)

```
after_validation(on: :create) do
  self.email= AESCrypt.encrypt(email, "password")
end
```

Comment: undefined method `after_validation' for DashboardUsersController:Class

Comment: Where i want to define?

Comment: Oh no, is an Active::Record method! You should put it in your model, not in the controller :)! Put it in `DashboardUser`

Comment: How to decrypt in view?

Comment: You're welcome :). Keep in mind that next time you'll get the record from the database, the password will be already encrypted. So the validation could fail. You should validate it only during creation, just add `on: :create` as a parameter to the `validates :email` (that you can now re-enable

Comment: you should be able to decrypt using `AESCrypt.decrypt`, if it doesn't work in the view, you have to decrypt in the controller and pass the decrypted mail to the view

Comment: if @dashboard_users != nil then
      dashboard_users.each do |usr|
        usrEmail = usr.email
        usr.email = AESCrypt.decrypt(usrEmail, "password")
      end
    end

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the data using using a method triggered by the `after_validation` callback. It is described here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

On its model you can just declare like the example scenario below:
E.g.:

```
after_validation :encrypt_cc_number, on: :create
```

It will validate then encrypt the credit car number on a create action.